# Replace double quotes with single quotes at the extremes of string only

Tags: jquery

I have a string

```
var myString = "[{"portal.home":"Home"},{"displaytag.tracking.id":"Item ID"}]";
```

I want the output as

```
myString  = '[{"portal.home":"Home"},{"displaytag.tracking.id":"Item ID"}]';
```

Comment: Have you tried doing it?

Comment: You understand that in the examples you've posted the quotes are not part of the strings, right?

Comment: yes with regex but it replaces all the double quotes. Problem is.. I dont know what content is going to be in the double quotes. I comes from the back end

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Right.. It is a malformed json. I want it to be in single quotes which will solve my purpose

Comment: Not sure about that. Strings are strings independently of the quoting around it (in JS the only difference between single and double quoted strings are the escaping inside of it); *if* your first line actually looked like that it'd return a syntax error due to the badly escaped string. Are the results you posted from Firebug or something? Developer tools usually represent strings between double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a string with double quotes, you cannot have unescaped double quotes inside it.

You cannot write

```
var myString = "A "B" C";
```

That will be a syntax error. However,

```
var myString = "A \"B\" C";
```

is exactly the same thing as:

```
var myString = 'A "B" C';
```

The resulting value of `myString` will be *exactly* the same. It's not like the first example will contain any escape markers in the final string. The escapes are only there to assist the creation of the string, which will be exactly `A "B" C`, in both cases; often wrapped in double quotes when being logged, to denote that the type is a string.

So if you run `console.log(myString);` it will say `"A "B" C"`, but the *value* of `myString` is simply `A "B" C`. This is simply a result of how the developer tools represent a string. There is nothing about the string itself that says that it was created with double quotes. The developer tools could equally well have just logged the value in a special color, but surrounding with double quotes happens to be the conventional way of denoting a string.

Comment: +1 awesome explanation. Just to add: these "outer" quotes do not affect JSON (as you've said, they return the exact same string value provided you do the proper escaping), in fact, the outer quotes shall not be part of the string `value` otherwise it will result in malformed JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with `.slice()`:

```
var newString =  "'" + myString.slice(1, -1) + "'";
```

Or with regex:

```
var newString = myString.replace(/^"|"$/g, "'");
```

Comment: That would remove the brackets. OP seems to have an issue with the string literal markers themselves.

Comment: @DavidHedlund: I'm not sure if `myString` is literally a JavaScript variable or just a way to say that "my string is". Without any sort of clarification, I can't tell for sure.

Comment: Indeed. It is a convoluted question. I'm betting that its rooted in a misunderstanding rather than an actual problem.